# Ruby and Google Charts - using gchartrb

Tags: ruby, charts

I'm having my first go at using Google charts using a Ruby wrapper called gchartrb.  My first attempt was to draw a bar chart, which works fairly well, except that the largest value (Trend 2 - 800) hits the top of the y axis.  I'm guessing this is a Google Charts issue, but I was wondering if there was a way around this problem so all values scale correctly?

```
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
GoogleChart::BarChart.new('800x200', "Bar Chart", :vertical, false) do |bc|
bc.axis :x, :labels => labels, 
            :color => '000000' # Months
            bc.axis :y, :labels => [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900], 
            :color => '000000' # Number of books
  bc.data "Trend 1", [100,200,300,400], '0000ff'
  bc.data "Trend 2", [500,600,700,800], 'ff0000'
   bc.width_spacing_options :bar_width => 50, :bar_spacing => 0, :group_spacing => 0
  puts "\nBar Chart"
  puts bc.to_url
end
```

Comment: Even though, it is showing the largest value on top of y-axis, it is scaling all other values also correct for me. I am not sure, it was improved recently, but right now, i didn't have any errors/issues with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gave up on this gem and ended up using Google Charts directly.

Answer (score 0):

for scaling issue, there is an option called 'range' for bc.axis attribute like,

```
bc.axis :y, :color => '000000', :range => [0,max_scale_value]
```

you can set **max_scale_value** to me maximum value of your data values.
1) If you are displaying bars side by side, you can set max_scale_value to 800, as per your data. i.e. max value from both of your arrays.
2) If you are displaying stacked bars(one above the other), then you should set max_scale_value to be maximum of [(100+500),(200+600),(300+700),(400+800)]
3) you need to remove labels property for y -axis,because it will automatically scale as per the values and give you labels.

thus, you wont have the scaling issue.
Hope it helps :)